# Equidistance text layout in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image]

I have been trying to make this layout even. How can I have a vertical equidistance between the text and have them contained in the  card.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="card text-center">
        <p class="card-title"><small class="text-muted">Societal</small></p>
        <div class="card-body">
        <small class="card-text">Large involontary migration</small>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">10.5%</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for achieving this listed in the bootstrap documentation.

[Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/)

I chose a slightly different card variation from bootstrap v4.5.

You can play around with the padding and margins to get it exactly how you'd like.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title text-danger text-center mb-0 pb-0">Societal</h5>
    <p class="card-text text-center mb-0 pb-0"><strong>Large-scale involontary migration</strong></p>
    <p class="text-danger text-center">10.5%</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

```
.card-body {
  border: 20px solid #b19cd9;
}
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AebiF.jpg)

[Code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/hbdsfz26/18/)